# create nodejs cli select/options menu

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, node-commander, vorpal.js

How do you create an arrow-key menu list?

I'm looking for something like after entering in `eslint init` or `create-react-app <project>`? (see images below)

### ESlint

[image: eslint CLI menu]

### yeoman

[image: create-react-app cli menu]

Searching around to find ways to create a CLI, I found NodeJS to be an option followed by a few tools: [Commander.js](https://github.com/tj/commander.js), [Vorpal](http://vorpal.js.org/), and/or [create-new-cli](https://github.com/dabit3/create-new-cli).

If I am on the right track, how can I create a CLI arrow-key select menu?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I believe `yeoman` is using [`inquirer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inquirer). Source: `yo`'s [dependencies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yo?activeTab=dependencies).

I've also seen [prompts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompts) which has a similar arrow selection feature and other cli ui/ux features. See the demos about halfway down the page.

Note: I've never actually used either, I'm just in the same research phase.

Comment: Inquirer nailed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

looks like 'inquirer' (npm i inquirer)

also for progress bars and such you should look at clui (npm i clui)

for parsing commands most use commander (npm commander) or the open cli framework (npm i oclif) - you can also look at yargs (very similar to commander, npm i yargs)

inquirer and clui work very well with both command parsers.

Have fun.